# How does Frobenius act in this field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand the following derivation of how does Frobenius acts in the field  $\mathbb{F}_{p}$

First we consider the following diagram:

$$\mathbb{F}_{p} - \mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha) -\mathbb{F}_{p}^{al}$$

where $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{al}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ and $\alpha$ is a root of $P(x)=x^2-\overline{a} \in \mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is not square in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, so we can define the following mapping:

$$x=c+d \alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha) \to x'=c-d \alpha$$

and then we can use Gauss sums, and we know that $S^l_p=(\frac{p}{l})S_p$ where $(\frac{p}{l})$ is the Jacobi symbol, so assuming that $p \equiv 1 \mod l$ we get that $Fr(\sqrt p)= (\frac{p}{l}) \sqrt p $

So my questions are,

> What happens if we don't have $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is not square in
>   $\mathbb{F}_{p}$? and
>
> Can someone clarify this derivation or make it more explicit please
>   (this is Why it uses Gauss sums?, Why can it assume that $p \equiv 1
> > \mod l$?, Why it turns out that $Fr(\sqrt p)= (\frac{p}{l}) \sqrt p $
>   )?

So what can be done? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: So then, what can be done?